# How to update value of variable declared outside lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Came across the following code today, it converts the input seconds in Long to a format like `2days, 3hours, 1min, 5s`. My problem with this is the use of `final long[] secondsCpy = { seconds };`. Any variable inside a lambda has to be final or effectively final, so, using an array variable is kind of a hack. Is there a better way to do this?

```
    private static final LinkedHashMap<String, Long> readableTimeFormatMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>() {
        {
           put("day", TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1));
           put("hr", TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1));
           put("min", TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
           put("sec", TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(1));
        }
     };


    public static String getReadableTime(final long seconds) {

        final StringJoiner readableTime = new StringJoiner(" ");

        final long[] secondsCpy = { seconds };

        readableTimeFormatMap.forEach((displayString, divider) -> {
            readableTime.add(getReadableTimeUnit(displayString, secondsCpy[0] / divider));
            secondsCpy[0] = secondsCpy[0] % divider;
        });

        return readableTime.toString().trim();
    }
```

Comment: return any value _from_ your lambda with a combination of `map` and `collect`, instead of using `foreach` --> no need of any final variable this way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no much better way to do this, you can use for example [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well without complicating things, you could always resort to using an enhanced for loop.

```
long secondsCpy = seconds;
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    readableTime.add(getReadableTimeUnit(entry.getKey(), secondsCpy / entry.getValue()));
    secondsCpy = secondsCpy % entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: You don’t even need the `secondsCpy`, as `seconds` will not be used for anything else in this method.

Comment: @Holger in the question you can see that `seconds` is a final variable, so it is necessary to do a copy.

Comment: Yeah, we could use this too, but wanted to see if it can be done using a lambda function. Thanks!

Comment: @Kermi or you remove that `final` modifier. It has no practical relevance anyway (besides making a second variable necessary).